# nginx (1.1.19) socket-level configuration of tcp_nodelay

Tags: c, sockets, nginx, tcp

I'm curious about
https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/core/ngx_connection.c

Specifically, line 838 in `ngx_configure_listening_sockets()`:

```
#if 0
          if (1) {
              int tcp_nodelay = 1;

              if (setsockopt(ls[i].fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY,
                         (const void *) &tcp_nodelay, sizeof(int))
                  == -1) //old-the current code calls an internal function to do this
              {
                  ngx_log_error(NGX_LOG_ALERT, cycle->log, ngx_socket_errno,
                                "setsockopt(TCP_NODELAY) %V failed, ignored",
                                &ls[i].addr_text);
              }
          }
  #endif
```

Using `getsockopt`, I was indeed able to determine that none of my `accept` sockets had `TCP_NODELAY` set.  Removing the preprocessor block fixed this.  But why is it there?  If the intention is to configure the accepted socket later and explicitly, I can't figure out where this is happening.

This app builds full responses before calling send, so traditional wisdom would be to disable nagle(enable `TCP_NODELAY`), but ***I figure there is either a *correct* way to enable `TCP_NODELAY` or nginx has a very good reason for not enabling it.***

Am I correct, and if so, which is it?

(for the record, this question mostly involves

Comment: The code you show sets TCP_NODELAY on the listening socket - which may be inherited by the accept()'ed sockets - but that isn't portable. The same file has a `ngx_tcp_nodelay()`  function to set TCP_NODELAY on the (non-listening) TCP sockets which are called from various places, depending on settings you have in nginx.conf

Comment: @nos - I truly couldn't figure out from where.  There was a `sendfile` type of socket where it was obvious, but `nginx` has a 2-bit field in its internal structure for tcp_nodelay, and I really couldn't figure out anything consistent in how it was 1) set or 2) used.  Not saying it's it not consistent.  Just that if it is, I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: run e.g  `grep -r ngx_tcp_nodelay\( .` to see where it's called from.

Comment: @nos - Ah yes...It's clear what to do in the new nginx.  My version doesn't have that function, the file that calls it, or the setting that file reads.  You've answered the important part of my question for me, which is that they probably `#ifdefed` that out for portability reasons (vs a deliberate attempt to enable nagle regardless of config).  Thank you.

Comment: the *relevant* file (for the socket type in question) that calls it, I should say